# Cannot find Valgrind executable for use with CLion?

Tags: c++, valgrind, clion

I am trying to connect Valgrind with CLion 2020.2.1 for testing purposes, but CLion (and perhaps I) cannot locate the Valgrind executable.

The path I am currently using is:

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\valgrind`

But when I try to run anything with Valgrind using this path I get a message stating that it cannot run the program because of this error:

`CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Which seemed to make sense upon further research, as what I am selecting (\usr\bin\valgrind) appears to be a .cpp source file and not an executable - as the error would indicate - but now I don't know what the issue is. If that isn't what CLion is looking for, then where is the file it is looking for?

Have also tried path '/usr/bin/valgrind/' which resulted in "Valgrind executable not found." when I tried to compile.

If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Open  wsl shell. Type `/usr/bin/valgrind` at the prompt. Press enter. What do you get?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I get "valgrind: no program specified  valgrind: Use --help for more information." I checked /usr/local/bin and it is empty.

Comment: So you have valgrind installed, and it is an executable, not a C program text. To verify, type `file /usr/bin/valgrind`. No idea what is wrong but see [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/memory-profiling-with-valgrind.html#valgrind-wsl). "To use Valgrind on Windows via WSL, provide the 'subsystem' path to Valgrind, which is /usr/bin/valgrind by default, instead of the actual Windows location of the Valgrind binary. However, this path will not be valid until you select the CMake profile connected to the WSL toolchain..."

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux executables (and native Linux executables) are ELF (Executable and Linker Format) format; Windows executables are PE (Portable Executable) format.  Windows can't natively run ELF format executables as far as I know except with the help of the WSL layer. `/usr/bin/valgrind` is probably ELF format. That is why it is not a valid Win32 application; you're trying to run it from Windows instead of from WSL.